# Synchronizing jQuery animations for Chrome, Safari, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

What is the best/correct way to go about synchronizing animations with jQuery? I need to remove the small jitter in the animation for a horizontal accordion.

Here is a link to the issue (the site is a work in progress). http://repaintthecity.com/new/index_2.html

Here is a copy of the problem in jsfiddle, if the test site is acting up: http://jsfiddle.net/cj4MQ/1/

The animation jitter happens on the right-most block. I've tried messing with the animation queue, but no implementation seems to remove the jitter completely. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a nice design. I don't see any jitter anywhere with Chrome 16/Linux. On an unrelated note, have you considered changing the easing a bit? I found the movement felt a little bit odd, and I'm guessing it's because (as far as I can tell) the speed is uniform throughout the animation.

Comment: Thank you. The jitter is least apparent in the latest version of Firefox, but it still seems most apparent for me in Chrome 16/OS X Lion.

I have been messing with different easing options, but I restored everything back to standard to try to eliminate the jitter.

Comment: it seems to be fine with my chrome and firefox on windows 7. didn't see any jitter.

Comment: Hmm..strange. The jittering I see if very slight..just a quick move left to right, except in Chrome, where the jittering is very apparent. How could it be that I see jittering, but you guys don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems like both animations are happening at the same time, they are not. For all practical purposes, imagine them taking turns changing their widths. (read http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

The simple answer is you can't and probably shouldn't. You are animating 2 widths in a single threaded javascript process. You are bound to encounter jittering no matter what if you try to animate it this way.

You can try to hide the jittering by animating the container width to a fixed width while forcing the last element right.